# How to detect a modal view is visible globally in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

In SwiftUI, there're couple of ways to present a modal view like `.popover`.

My background is I would like to present a UIKit modal view somewhere else rather than under the current view page with

```swift
private func presentGlobally(animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        var rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.rootViewController
        while true {
          if let presented = rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
            rootViewController = presented
          } else if let navigationController = rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            rootViewController = navigationController.visibleViewController
          } else if let tabBarController = rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
            rootViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController
          } else {
            break
          }
        }
        UIApplication.shared.rootViewController?.present(self, animated: animated, completion: completion)
    }
```

The above approach does not work because SwiftUI gave an error of

`` [Presentation] Attempt to present <BuyersCircle_iOS.GlobalModalUIKit: 0x15b82f000> on <*TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentGS1_GS1_GS1_GS1_V16BuyersCircle_iOS11ContentViewGVS_30_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifierGSqCS2_11UserService___GS4_GSqCS2_11GlobalModal___GS4_GSqCS2_9CartModel___GS4_GSqCS2_19ReachabilityMonitor___GS4_GSqCS2_19PartialSheetManager*___: 0x158715600> (from

So I'm thinking

- If I can get the current SwiftUI modal view controller, so I can present the UIKit modal based on it. I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you algorithm you're calculating `rootViewController` but then presenting `self` to `UIApplication.shared.rootViewController`, not to the found `rootViewController`

Replace

```
UIApplication.shared.rootViewController?.present(self, animated: animated, completion: completion)
```

With

```
rootViewController?.present(self, animated: animated, completion: completion)
```